# Checkbox Send Multiple Options in Form

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

Having an issue with receiving multiple options.

I have a form and I have just implemented a checkbox into my html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="bookingoptions" value="1">  
<input type="checkbox" name="bookingoptions" value="2">          
<input type="checkbox" name="bookingoptions" value="3">
```

At the moment the form uses send_booking_email.php.

```
<form id="booking-form" form name="bookingform" method="post" action="send_booking_email.php">
```

Within send_booking_email.php:

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST['email'])) {


    $email_to = "test@test.com";

    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['bookingoptions'])) {   

    }

    $bookingoptions = $_POST['bookingoptions']; // required

    $email_message .= "Booking Options:".clean_string($bookingoptions)."\n";



// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>


<?php

}

?>
```

This works fine when one option is selected, however I am unable to get it to send multiple selections.

I believe it is due to:

```
$email_message .= "Booking Options:".clean_string($bookingoptions)."\n";
```

Being only able to store one value? If so is there a way around this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename this field to `bookingoptions[]` and you will get array for $_POST['bookingoptions']

```
<input type="checkbox" name="bookingoptions[]" value="1">  
<input type="checkbox" name="bookingoptions[]" value="2">          
<input type="checkbox" name="bookingoptions[]" value="3">
```

then implode array elements into string:

```
clean_string(implode(', ', $bookingoptions))
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help... Working now!

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="bookingoptions_1" value="1">  
<input type="checkbox" name="bookingoptions_2" value="2">          
<input type="checkbox" name="bookingoptions_3" value="3">
```

then next php side

```
$x=1;
$bookingoptions="";


 while (isset($_POST['bookingoptions_' . $x])) {

     if($x==1)
     {
        $bookingoptions .=$_POST['bookingoptions_' . $x];
     }
     else
        {
     $bookingoptions .=','.$_POST['bookingoptions_' . $x];
 }

    $x++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the POST request as an array of booking options like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="bookingoptions[]" value="1">
```

Do this for all the input tags with name bookingoptions replacing bookingoptions to bookingoptions[]